# Making a div fill blank space in parent

Tags: html, css

There is a master `<div>` which will be separated into two `<div>`s that are `30%` and `70%` of its `width`.

The 30% piece called `outerContainer` has some text in a `<a>` child and another child `<div>` called `container` that needs to take up the remaining space.

My attempt to make the `container` have a `width` and `height` of `100%`, thinking it would fill the  `outerContainer` did not work.

The `container` is taking the `width` and `height` of `outerContainer` (it seems like) and not filling up the remaining space like I want it to.

```css
.master {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
}
.outerContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.text {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="text"><a href="#">Some </a>Text</div>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2ohd8cv/10/)

Comment: add margin-top:-20px; to container) not sure this is the best way

Comment: No, because the container will have elements inside it that shouldn't overlap the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can solve this easily using `flexbox`, applying `flex-direction:column` to  `.outerContainer`, and `flex:1` in `.container`

> There will be an image inside the container

As mentioned by @pangloss the `min-height:0` in `.container` fixes the issue.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.master {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  display: flex
}
.outerContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  min-height:0;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
.container img{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="text"><a href="#">Some </a>Text</div>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/400" alt="img" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but I forgot to add a crucial part to my question. There will be an image inside the container. The reason why I want the container is to set the boundaries for the image so its max-height/width don't exceed the container. How would I do that? [~fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2ohd8cv/16/)

Comment: @Lolechi you can try adding `.container {min-height: 0;}` see it that works.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I will find a way tomorrow.